# Acessar variável através de exec

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, exec

Estava a tentar criar uma "shell" para poder comunicar com um programa em python durante a sua execução, até momento tenho o seguinte (este código é apenas um exemplo):

```
import sys, pygame
from threading import Thread
import math

pygame.init()

# INIT SCREEN
size = width, height = 800, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("teste")

black = 0,0,0
white = 255,255,255

rgb = 255,50,120

running = True

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

timer = 0
angulo = 0
x = 0
global x_var
x_var = 2

def process_input():
    while True:
        c = input("Python Shell > ")
        exec(c)



t = Thread(target=process_input)
t.daemon = True
t.start()

while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE: running = False


    angulo = ( angulo % 360 ) + 0.1
    sin = math.sin(angulo) * 50
    y = int( sin + height / 2)  


    x+= x_var

    pos = x,y

    rgb =  ( (rgb[0] % 255 ) +1 ) , ( (rgb[1] % 255 ) +1 ), ( (rgb[2] % 255 ) +1 )

    screen.set_at(pos, rgb)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

O meu objectivo seria alterar uma variável em tempo de execução, por exemplo alterar `x_var` de `2` para `-2` mas não estou a ter sucesso. Sou um pouco novo com python, mas já vi algo semelhante em outras situações.

Coloquei a variável `x_var` como `Global` até por que não sei o alcance do comando `exec`. Penso que o facto de ter o comando `process_input` em outra thread poderá estar a afectar o acesso, porém preciso de ter sempre um loop em execução.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há muitos, muitos senões com a forma como você está fazendo esse programa - 
mas, isso faz parte das coisas que escrevemos quando estamos entendendo como programar.
O principal talvez seja que suas estruturas de controle não fazem parte de nenhuma função e estão "soltas" no código do módulo.

No entanto, essa dúvida pontual é fácil de responder: o `exec`  e o `eval`, por padrão tem seu código executado num dicionário de variáveis novo, sme nenhuma variável - mas ambos aceitam como parâmetros dicionários para serem usados como o namespace de variáveis globais e locais.

Como o seu intuito aí é alterar variáveis globais, basta passar o dicionário de variáveis globais, que em Python é retornado quando chamamos `globals()` como segundo parâmetro para o `exec`:

```
def process_input():
    while True:
        c = input("Python Shell > ")
        exec(c, globals())
```

Funciona assim:

```
In [1]: b = 10

In [2]: exec(input("teste: "), globals())
teste: b = 20

In [3]: b
Out[3]: 20
```

Se você mantiver e evoluir esse programa, eventualmente o código dentro do loop principal do pygame vai ficar numa função. Você pode então criar um objeto de namespace só para manter todas as variáveis que atualmente são locais, e passar o `.__dict__` desse objeto como parâmetro de globais para o exec.